# List event receivers not triggered after quick editing/grid editing

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, event-handlers

I have a custom Sharepoint 2013 list with event receivers attached to it (adding, updating, deleting).

However, it looks like the event receivers are not triggered when the user is adding/editing in quick edit mode/grid edit mode, e.g. when the content of the list is edited as if it was Excel.

The event receivers work fine when editing/adding through the regular forms.

How do I get SharePoint 2013 to trigger event receivers when the user is editing through the grid edit mode?

Comment: Apparently, no one is looking at this, but Workflow Item Created events are not firing (i.e. workflows that run on item created are not starting) either if a new item is added via quick edit. Very annoying.

Comment: @RobertLee, ok, at least its not only me. Might this be a bug in SP2013, or is there a good reason for this behaviour?

Comment: THe issue was fixed for 2010 only in March 2012. I wonder if 2013 considered/included this already https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4835.sharepoint-2010-datasheet-view-now-supports-event-receiver-custom-error-messages-hotfix-issued.aspx

Comment: To my knowledge because the DataSheet is practically asynchronous call to SP-WS, I've heard people experiencing this with Sychronous events. Would you be able to change that in your events declaration in Elements.xml file and test for Asynchronous execution?

Comment: thanks for the hint, this did the trick. I've changed "added" and "updated" events back to "async" and it worked like a charm. The only question is, how to get the "sync" events to run, because I have some plausibility checks in those. Would you use JSLink instead? Best Regards, Stan.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that in SP2013 the gridview/datasheet editing is only triggering the async events (like ItemUpdated). The AfterProperties contains only fields that were changed.

When using the default editform the AfterProperties contain all fields that are on the form, even the fields that were not changed.