# Item Added Event receiver Issue in quick Edit

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, custom-list, event-receivers, site-template

I have Created item added event receiver which is bind with the custom generic list.
Using the values of field in list i am creating new sub site by specific custom template definition.
When i am add one item as routine practice Item Added event receiver works fantastic.
But when i am passing 4 items using quick edit feature in share point list.
**i.e. ItemE1 ,Item E2,Item E3,Item E4.**

In Case of multi items creating, Item Added Event receiver works for only last item "E4".

I am not getting any specific information in logs.

What will be best practice to work with Event Receiver?

Comment: Similar question. Check comments http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62753/list-event-receivers-not-triggered-after-quick-editing-grid-editing

Comment: Question is not with understandable answers